# Removing duplicate values without using distinct

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have written the below query using BigQuery and it gives me duplicate article values. I have tried using distinct but it doesn't seem to work somehow so now I'm looking into removing the duplicates with other methods.

```
select
      replace(article, ' - paper', '') as p,
      pageviews,
      login_clicks,
      paywall_clicks
    from analytics.article_action_week
```

Comment: FYI, `select distinct` works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: Can you try distinct and then copy and paste two repeated rows?

Comment: @SaimNazir . . . Please explain what  YOU mean by "unique".  BigQuery removes what IT thinks are duplicates when you use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation in BigQuery to remove duplicates:

```
select replace(article, ' - paper', '') as p,
       any_value(struct(pageviews, login_clicks, paywall_clicks)
                ).*
from analytics.article_action_week aaw
group by p;
```

Note:  This returns an arbitrary row.  I might suggest from the context, that you actually want aggregation:

```
select replace(article, ' - paper', '') as p,
       sum(pageviews) as pageviews,
       sum(login_clicks) as login_clicks, 
       sum(paywall_clicks) as paywall_clicks
from analytics.article_action_week aaw
group by p;
```

This will add up the measures across the different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using `row_number()` :

```
select replace(wk.article, ' - paper', '') as p, wk.pageviews, wk.login_clicks, wk.paywall_clicks, 
       row_number() over (partition by replace(wk.article, ' - paper', '') order by ?) as seq
from analytics.article_action_week wk;
```

You can filtered seq with `1` to get unique rows. Use ordering column instead `?`

Answer (score 0):

group by feature can be helpful.

```
select
  replace(article, ' - paper', '') as p,
  pageviews,
  login_clicks,
  paywall_clicks
from analytics.article_action_week group by article
```